# nautilus behaves differently when typing text than before

Tags: nautilus

Usually when i was inside a folder (nautilus) and just typed something in, a small textbox would popup at the bottom right and it would highlight the file that matches that string.

Now when i type something in it automatically performs a search. How can i make it behave like it did before?

Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way:

```
dconf-editor
```

/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/enable-interactive-search

"Use default value: off"

"Custom value: True"

**Or:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search "true"
```